# how can i apply ml on kafka and spark structured streaming without getting pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

how can i apply ml on kafka and spark structured streaming without getting pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start(); kafka

in the code below  m trying to read a json file from kafka add it to spark and then train a model in real time

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, from_json
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, DoubleType
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import RegressionEvaluator`

# Initialize a Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('topic').getOrCreate()

schema = StructType([
    StructField("Index", DoubleType(), True),
    StructField("col1", StringType(), True),
    StructField("cel2", DoubleType(), True),
    StructField("cel3", DoubleType(), True),
    StructField("col4", DoubleType(), True),
    StructField("col5", DoubleType(), True)
])

df = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
    .option("subscribe", "topic") \
    .option("inferSchema", "false") \
    .load() \
    .select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema).alias("data")) \
    .selectExpr("data.*")

# Create a VectorAssembler to combine the feature columns into a single vector column
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=["col1", "col2"],
                            outputCol="Assembler",
                            handleInvalid="keep")

# Transform the DataFrame with the assembler to create the new column Features
df = assembler.transform(df)

streaming_query = df \
    .writeStream \
    .format("console") \
    .start() \

splits = df.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])
train_df = splits[0]
test_df = splits[1]

lr = LinearRegression(featuresCol='Assembler', labelCol='col4', maxIter=10, regParam=0.3, elasticNetParam=0.8)

# Fit the model to the training data using writeStream.start()
model = lr.fit(train_df)
print("Coefficients: " + str(model.coefficients))
print("Intercept: " + str(model.intercept))

trainingSummary = model.summary
print("RMSE: %f" % trainingSummary.rootMeanSquaredError)
print("r2: %f" % trainingSummary.r2)

train_df.describe().show()

lr_predictions = model.transform(test_df)
lr_predictions.select("prediction","col4","features").show(5)

lr_evaluator = RegressionEvaluator(predictionCol="prediction", \
                 labelCol="col4",metricName="r2")
print("R Squared (R2) on test data = %g" % lr_evaluator.evaluate(lr_predictions))

# Stop the query and print the model summary
model.stop()
print(model.summary)

streaming_query.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Did you search your error? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Queries+with+streaming+sources+must+be+executed+with+writeStream.start